# Javascript get currently playing song in Itunes for Windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows-10, itunes

I would like to get currently playing song's name (and artist if possible) on Itunes. I'm using Itunes Version 12.10.3.1 on Windows 10. 
I only want to get both strings in Javascript and get them into variables.

It seems that Applescript could be a way to do it but i can't find any interface to execute applescript inside JS...
Could somebody help ?

Comment: is it even possible? iTunes is a standalone app and won't expose any data outside due to privacy. How would JS running else where be able to get iTunes's application state?

Comment: Well i saw topics where you could get it via applescript, but i don't think it's working anymore. However it should still be possible i think

Comment: so are you look for solution using JavaScript as stated, or AppleScript?

Comment: I'd like to use Javascript, and even though some people were using applsescript via node modules, they are now out of date today... Actually if there is still a way to execute applescript in JS i could take this solution as well. All I need is a way to get the song name as a string in my JS script.

Comment: AppleScript might be possible, as it provides interface into apps on the Mac... so you might have to use AppleScript alone or together with JS

Comment: Yeah, but i was wondering if it also works on Windows 10... I don't really know how applescript work though
I edited my post about it